# Custom list view in console app

Tags: lightning-apps, custom-console-components

I want to use a Lightning console app, but instead of the standard left pane listing all items of a particular object type, I want to use my own component (which I intend to be an accordion containing several lists), but with the items still linked to the right-side detail view in the way they are in a normal console app.

Is there any way to use a custom component for the left-hand list view in a Lightning console app?